# Is this coercion? Why is R telling me these are the same data types?

Tags: r, dataframe, coercion

In a dataframe, I want to be able to separate columns with numeric types from columns with strings/characters.

Here is my data:

```
test=data.frame(col1=sample(1:20,10),col2=sample(31:50,10),
col3=sample(101:150,10),col4=sample(c('a','b','c'),10,replace=T))
```

Which looks like

```
   col1 col2 col3 col4
1     2   41  132    c
2    11   47  141    b
3    13   39  135    a
4    12   31  117    b
5    19   42  106    a
6     8   50  118    a
7    14   33  149    a
8     6   48  148    b
9    16   37  150    b
10    9   34  140    a
```

Now here is the strange thing if I do typeof a row/col containing a character, R says it is an integer

```
> typeof(test[1,4])
[1] "integer"
```

If I do something like this

```
> apply(test,2,typeof)
       col1        col2        col3        col4 
"character" "character" "character" "character"
```

R says they are all characters. Also,

```
> lapply(test,typeof)
[1] "integer" "integer" "integer" "integer"
```

Again, what is going on and is there a good way to distinguish between columns with characters and columns with integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apply` works on arrays and matrices, not data frames.

To work on a data frame, it first converts it to a matrix.

Your data frame has a factor column, so array converts everything to characters. Without bothering to tell you.

As you have seen, `sapply` is the way to go, and `class` is probably the thing you want to find out. Although there's also `mode`, `typoeof`, and `storage.mode` depending on what you want to know:

```
> test$col5=letters[1:10]  # really character, not a factor
> test$col3=test$col3*pi # lets get some decimals in there


> sapply(test, mode)
       col1        col2        col3        col4        col5 
  "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric" "character" 
> sapply(test, class)
       col1        col2        col3        col4        col5 
  "integer"   "integer"   "numeric"    "factor" "character" 
> sapply(test, typeof)
       col1        col2        col3        col4        col5 
  "integer"   "integer"    "double"   "integer" "character" 
> sapply(test, storage.mode)
       col1        col2        col3        col4        col5 
  "integer"   "integer"    "double"   "integer" "character"
```

Comment: There is no character column in the data.frame. It's a factor.

Comment: True. `apply` coerces factors into characters, see: `as.matrix(test)`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured out my own question, sorry:

```
sapply(test,class)
```

Answer (score 0):

`col4` is a factor:

```
str(test)
#'data.frame':  10 obs. of  4 variables:
#$ col1: int  11 14 8 19 10 12 7 18 3 16
#$ col2: int  46 39 35 38 42 37 34 32 41 31
#$ col3: int  113 147 138 118 132 139 131 119 108 111
#$ col4: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 3 2 3 2 3 3 3 1 3
```

A factor internally is an integer (as reported by `typeof`) with class `factor` and a `levels` attribute. `apply` coerces the data.frame to a matrix. Since a matrix can hold only one data type, everything is coerced to characters before applying `typeof`.

Use `class` to distinguish between the data types and `lapply` (or `sapply`)  to loop over the columns.

Answer (score 0):

data.frame(col4=sample(c('a','b','c'),10,replace=T)) the col4 is a factor.

apply(test,2,typeof):
if dim(test) == 2L it will use as.matrix(test) firstly.